# Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime Going Into Limited State

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My team have created an IR in an on-premises VM and we are trying to create a Linked Service to an on-prem DB using that IR

Whenever we click on Test Connection in the Linked Service, the connection fails and IR goes into a limited state

We also whitelisted the IPs provided by Microsoft for IR ADF and also checked the network traces and all seems fine there

Also, we stopped and restarted the IR, uninstalled and installed it again but still the problem resists

Have anyone faced a similar kind of issue?

As this has been a long time we are facing this issue which has now become a blocker for us

Thanks!

Comment: yes, but not able to view it now

Comment: added back now 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is observed  when nodes can't communicate with each other.

You can Log in to the node-hosted virtual machine (VM). Go to **Applications and Services Logs**  >  **Integration Runtime**, open Event Viewer, and filter the error logs. If you find the error `System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException` or `Cannot connect to worker manager`

Follow the official documentation with detailed steps for Troubleshooting **Error message**: [Self-hosted integration runtime node/logical self-hosted IR is in Inactive/ "Running (Limited)" state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/self-hosted-integration-runtime-troubleshoot-guide?tabs=data-factory#error-message-self-hosted-integration-runtime-nodelogical-self-hosted-ir-is-in-inactive-running-limited-state)

As it states:

> try one or both of the following methods to fix:
>
> ```
> -   Put all the nodes in the same domain.
> -   Add the IP to host mapping in all the hosted VM's host files.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue. Our organization has firewall rules preventing specific ports or url's from outside network. We added Data factory services tags with internet facing in Route table, and IR then connected successfully.